# Pass only one location of ram to another module in verilog

Tags: verilog, ram

I have a fetch module which fetches the instruction from the memory(test bench in this case) and i want to pass only one location(8 bits) from the ram(test bench) to the fetch module.How do I perform the instantiation?

```
module fetch_tb;

reg clk,rst,wrt,rd;
reg [7:0] addr;
reg [7:0] instr_mem[127:0];
reg PR_in;

wire [7:0] instr_out_fetch;
wire PR_out;

 fetch UUT3(.instr_in_fetch(instr_mem),.addr(addr),.PR_in(PR_in), .PR_out(PR_out),   .clk(clk), .rst(rst));
```

and the fetch module is as follows

```
module fetch(instr_in_fetch,PR_in,PR_out,clk,rst,instr_out_fetch,addr);

input [7:0] instr_in_fetch;
input clk,rst,rd;
input [7:0] addr;
input PR_in;

output reg PR_out;
output reg [7:0] instr_out_fetch;
```

Comment: I am a little confused what you are trying to do. the question title states passing one location, but your comment on the solution requests several locations. If you could clarify the question may be adding in what you expect the outputs to be for a given input.

Answer (score 0):

This passes the 8 bits at memory location 0.

```
 fetch UUT3(.instr_in_fetch(instr_mem[0]),.addr(addr),.PR_in(PR_in), .PR_out(PR_out),   .clk(clk), .rst(rst));
```

Comment: OK,but how do I pass several 8 bit data from the test bench based on the address,because, the way I am feeding the data is

     **instr_out_fetch <= instr_in_fetch[addr];**

and your code can send only the data present in the zeroth location? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Maybe you want `.instr_in_fetch(instr_mem[addr])`.  It's hard for me to tell what you want with so little code.